# Restrict import to specific path, without restricting the imported module's path

Tags: python, import, sys.path

Is it possible to import a module from a specific directory, without affecting the import path of the imported module?

If I was to temporarily replace `sys.path` with the desired directory, the imported module would not be able to import anything outside of that directory.

I don't want to just prepend `sys.path` with the directory, because I don't want importing to fall back to another source.

Comment: So you want to import a specific module *only* if it exists in a specific directory? Why not prepend the path to `sys.path`, import, and test if the correct module was imported? Or test if the module file exists before importing?

Comment: I suppose I could check if the directory contains a `__init__.py` file, and only import it if it does. If I was to check if the module came from the correct location after importing, cleaning up would be a little tricky.

Comment: @eryksun, that's just the kind of control I was looking for! If you make an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library's [imp module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp) allows you to search a list of paths to find and import a module without altering `sys.path`. For example:

```
import imp

search_paths = [path_to_spam]
modfile, modpath, description = imp.find_module('spam', search_paths)
with modfile:
    spam = imp.load_module('spam', modfile, modpath, description)
```